# collection_select issue ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select

i'm new with ruby on rails and i've an issue.
In my app, an user can publish an idea and ideas belongs to activities. 
So user can choose with a select which activity they want.
Here's my code for my form, i used collection_select

```
<div class="field">
<%=  collection_select(:idee, :id, Activite.all, :id, :nom, prompt: true) %></div>
```

The select input work, i've all my activities in the select input but when i select activity and publish my idea, the idea don't take the value and stay empty.
Even when i edit idea, the idea don't take the value of the activity.

How can i resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have an Idea and an Activity model and that you are building a form for an idea, I think you should write the collection_select as:

```
<%=  collection_select(:idea, :activity_id, Activity.all, :id, :nom, prompt: true) %>
```

I suggest you to use form_for syntax if you are not already doing it.

check apidock for reference: 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for